# Reading Matrix File (mtx) using Python: not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, matrix

I want to read a ".mtx file" using Python. The matrix file (31x31) is given by a transportation simulation tool (visum). I used the following code:

```
from scipy.io import mmread
A = mmread('./saclay/demand_visum.mtx')
```

I got the message:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've investigated a little and found that there is a library for loading the files, called [matrixconverters](https://pypi.org/project/matrixconverters/), you can load a PTV Visum matrix by using the following command:

```
from matrixconverters.read_ptv import ReadPTVMatrix
the_matrix = ReadPTVMatrix(filename="pathtoyourfile")
```

That's a short answer, it works with some exports, not with others, depending on your format. The concrete MTX subformat is the text in the first line of your .mtx file, for example: `$V;D3` format didn't work for me, but others did.